# how to take a value from a given range and map it to a new range?

Tags: javascript

how to take a value from a given range and map it to a new range.

I mean if I have range A :   `0 → 100` (0,1,2,3,4,...) and range B: `0 → 1000` if I chose `0` from **range A** we should get `0` from **range B** or if we chose `50` in the **range A** we should get `500` in **range B**, etc...

the function should be something like :

```
mapRange(Chosen value, min of range A, max of range A, min of range B, max of range B)
```

I have tied a math equation for this :

```
( Chosen value/max of range A)*max of range B
```

But it doesn't include minimums of the ranges.

There are some library solutions out there but I have no idea how to implement this in pure javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any efforts so far ?

Comment: I have used p5.js ...

Comment: Compute the fraction of the value in the source range compared to the size of the source range, then multiply that by the size of the target range and add the result to the starting value of the target range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by computing the offset into the range and then applying it to the new range, for example:

```js
function convertRange(value, currentRange, newRange) {
  // Convert the value into a number from 0-1 (0 meaning start of range and 1 end of range)
  let offset = (value - currentRange.start) / (currentRange.end - currentRange.start);
  
  // Apply offset to new range
  return newRange.start + offset * (newRange.end - newRange.start);
}

let range1 = {start: 0, end: 100};
let range2 = {start: 0, end: 1000};
console.log(convertRange(0, range1, range2));
console.log(convertRange(50, range1, range2));
console.log(convertRange(100, range1, range2));
```

Comment: I'll try this...

Answer (score 1):

Beside the given answer, i suggest to organize the function as closure over the given ranges and return a functionwhich takes only a single value. This approach allows to use it as mapping function for arrays, for example.

```js
function f(minA, maxA, minB, maxB) {
    return function (x) {
        return (x - minA) * (maxB - minB) / (maxA - minA) + minB;
    };
}

console.log(f(0, 100, 0, 1000)(50));
```